# terraform local-exec ausführen

Tags: terraform

I would like to perform the following scenario in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "jenkins" {
  name = var.image_name
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./deploy-image.sh ${self.repository_url} ${var.image_name}"
  }
}
```

However, it is not executed. Does anyone have an idea what could be?

Comment: Any chance you can translate this to English please? Questions need to be in English to be on topic here.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I mean the script in command will not be executed when running ```terraform apply````

Comment: Can you also show the output of an apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add a working directory

```
resource "null_resource" "backend_image" {
  triggers = {
    build_trigger = var.build_trigger
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "./deploy-image.sh ${var.region} ${var.image_name} ${var.ecr_repository}"
    interpreter = ["bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = "${path.cwd}/${path.module}"
  }
}
```

Now it works.

Comment: Hi Awiechert, Could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297188/terraform-unable-to-run-multiple-commands-in-local-exec I'm facing the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sweta Sharma, do you still need help?

Comment: Thanks so much, Aweichert for your reply, I found the solution.